# How to resolve "The maximum permissible key length is 900 bytes."

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Signature]
(
    [caption_id] [nvarchar](512) NOT NULL,
    [signature_id] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

I want to add the primary key with following alter command:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Signature] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [pk__signatures] 
 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([caption_id] ASC,[signature_id] ASC);
```

When the above alter command is executed, I get the following error:

Msg 1944, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Index 'pk__signatures' was not created. This index has a key length of at least 1028 bytes. The maximum permissible key length is 900 bytes.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: You want to add a 1024+4 bytes long key? That's maddness. In general, it's usually a bad idea to have a varchar/nvarchar primary key. Why do you need that? What's your problem?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2011/01/06/optionsforindexedlookupsoflongvalues.aspx

Comment: An ID of 512 length seems a bit much to me. The use of wide characters doesn't make it better. And as Luaan already noted: wide keys don't perform well. You could either use normal characters. That'll give you a key of 516 length. Not beautiful but doable. Or add a column with a hash value of your ID. Since collisions are rare (with good hash functions), you'll keep the uniqueness property but have an acceptable key length.

Comment: Nasty, very Nasty. Please give a little more info why you want to make a (n)varchar column your primary key. The problem with this is that your index will take more space up than the actual data in the table.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look here It may help you
[Living with SQL's 900 Byte Index Key Length Limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bartd/living-with-sqls-900-byte-index-key-length-limit)